# Unable to move the second robot using nav2d exploration

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, nav2d, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to explore an area autonomously using multiple robots. I have created a launch file which looks like below:

```
<node name="R0_MapAlign" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /robot_0/map 100"/>
<node name="R1_MapAlign" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /robot_1/map 100"/>

<!-- Start the first robot -->
<group ns="robot_0">
    <param name="robot_id" value="1"/>
    <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="robot_0"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/ros.yaml"/>

    <!-- Start the Navigator to move the robot autonomously -->
    <node name="Navigator" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="navigator" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/navigator.yaml"/>
    </node>
    
    <node name="GetMap" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="get_map_client"/>
    <node name="Explore" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="explore_client" output="screen"/>
    <node name="SetGoal" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="set_goal_client"/>

    <!-- Start the Operator to control the simulated robot -->
    <node name="Operator" pkg="nav2d_operator" type="operator">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/operator.yaml"/>
        <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/costmap.yaml" ns="local_map"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Start Mapper to genreate map from laser scans -->
    <node name="Mapper" pkg="nav2d_karto" type="mapper">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
    <remap from="karto_in" to="/shared_scans_r2"/>
    <remap from="karto_out" to="/shared_scans_r1"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/mapper.yaml"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Get URDF(Unified Robot Description Format), which is an XML format for representing a robot model for Pioneer3at-->
    <include file="$(find p2os_urdf)/launch/upload_pioneer3at.xml"/>
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0"/>
    </node>
    
    <node pkg="p2os_urdf" type="p2os_publisher_3at" name="publisher"/>
</group>

<!-- Start the second robot-->
<group ns="robot_1">
    <param name="robot_id" value="2"/>
    <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="robot_1"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/ros.yaml"/>
    
    <!-- Start the Navigator to move the robot autonomously -->
    <node name="Navigator" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="navigator" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/navigator.yaml"/>
    </node>

    <node name="GetMap" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="get_map_client"/>
    <node name="Explore" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="explore_client" output="screen"/>
    <node name="SetGoal" pkg="nav2d_navigator" type="set_goal_client"/>

     <!-- Start the Operator to control the simulated robot -->
    <node name="Operator" pkg="nav2d_operator" type="operator">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/operator.yaml"/>
        <rosparam file="$(find test_package)/param/costmap.yaml" ns="local_map"/>
    </node>
```

I am able to move the first robot for mapping and exploration, but the second robot does not moves. After I enter the command, nothing happens. For the first robot, it moves, but i get response:0 in the terminal.

Can anyone please help me with what is wrong with my program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219932/unable-to-move-the-second-robot-using-nav2d-exploration/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The second robot doesn't have a mapper in your launch file, so it won't be able to navigate. Have you tried to run tutorial4 from nav2d? This should already do what you are trying.

"response: 0" means everything is okay for the service call.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-10-27**:
Thanks Sebastian for your quick reply. I just checked my launch file has a mapper for the second robot. It just got truncated here. I also saw your response here http://answers.ros.org/question/192445/nav2d-autonomous-multi-robot-exploration/ and I have realized that I facing the same issue.

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-10-27**:
Is there any way I can automate the localization of second robot? Thanks again

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-10-28**:
If you buildt nav2d from source, there should be a localize_client (similar to the 3 existing clients) in the navigator package. If you start it, you can use the "Localize" service to do the initial movement.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-10-28**:
Check [here](https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/blob/master/nav2d_navigator/src/RobotNavigator.cpp#L581) to see what it does in detail. It simply moves straight until the navigator is initialized. It requires that the area around the robot is already mapped before calling this service.

**Comment by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on 2015-10-28**:
Thank you so much for your help.